# Ubuntu 16.04 - doesn't start after installation

Tags: server, 16.04

I just re-installed my Ubuntu server, twice, the installation works just fine it completes without errors and ask for reboot which I let it do.
After that the machine starts as normal but the screen goes black when Grub usually loads. After that nothing happens.

What can it be?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

try hitting right "shift" when booting to access grub.
press "e" to edit grub.
look for the line that has "quiet splash" in it.
write nomodeset after that line with a space before and after.
press f10 to reboot.
then it should be a matter of finding drivers for your graphics card.

worked for me.